# how to define empty variable in python

Tags: python, variables

consider this code:

```
str = "test"
def v():
    for i in str:
        k = k + i
        print(k)
```

I don't want to assign *k* anything at all. I used `k = None` to define empty variable but that doesn't work.

Comment: why doesn't it work? what error do you get?

Comment: Why do you want it to be empty? What does being empty mean?

Comment: @sharth Well `None+1` is going to cause an error.

Comment: If it's a string, empty is the empty string `k=""`

Comment: @ebarr it's `+i` not `+1`

Comment: A side-mistake: do not use `str` because it is a built-in function in Python (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

Comment: @jean-loup empty string worked fine thank you

Comment: @Trengot `None+anything` is going to fail.

Comment: @ebarr true, just me being pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
str="test"
def v():
    k = ""
    for i in str:
        k=k+i
        print(k)
```

Another advice, `str` is a built-in type in python you maybe  would like to change it for:

```
string="test"
def v():
    k = ""
    for i in string:
        k=k+i
        print(k)
```